# How to install php in Linux (Debian) on ChromeBook?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, php, chromebook

I am trying to install php in the Linux I set up, on my Chromebook,when activating developer mode. But, somehow it does seem to be working, despite a couple attempts on two different approaches:

1. https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/debian/how-to-install-php-7-3-7-2-7-1-on-debian-10-debian-9-debian-8.html

   Followed the link but I got this output:

   ```
   njtmendes@penguin:~$ sudo apt install -y php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-common
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package php7.4
   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
   E: Unable to locate package php7.4-cli
   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-cli'
   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-cli'
   E: Unable to locate package php7.4-common
   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-common'
   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-common'
   njtmendes@penguin:~$ ^C
   njtmendes@penguin:~$ php -v
   -bash: php: command not found
   njtmendes@penguin:~$ ^C
   njtmendes@penguin:~$
   ```
2. https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-php-7-4-on-ubuntu/
   I tried the solution above with the expectation of tweaking for Debiam but still doesn't work

   **output:**

   ```
   [6:16 pm, 28/04/2020] Nuno Da Elizabeth: njtmendes@penguin:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions are included. Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

   Debian oldstable and stable packages are provided as well: https://deb.sury.org/#debian-dpa

   You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

   BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
   https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

   CAVEATS:
   1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
   2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
   3. If you are using nginx, you are advise to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
      or ppa:ondrej/nginx

   PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

   WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see 
   https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

   # LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
   Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

   gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpmbr9q9y5/pubring.gpg' created
   gpg: /tmp/tmpmbr9q9y5/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
   gpg: key 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1
   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
   [6:17 pm, 28/04/2020] Helio: cool
   [6:18 pm, 28/04/2020] Helio: sudo apt-get update
   [6:18 pm, 28/04/2020] Nuno Da Elizabeth: njtmendes@penguin:~$ sudo apt-get update
   Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
   Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                     
   Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu groovy Release                                                                                       
     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
   Get:4 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease [6,760 B]                                                                                       
   Hit:5 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                  
   Hit:6 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                      
   Ign:7 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/81 buster InRelease
   Hit:8 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/81 buster Release
   Get:9 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 Packages [136 kB]
   Reading package lists... Done    
   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   ```

   **The output of the `apt update**

   ```
   njtmendes@penguin:~$ sudo apt update
   Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
   Hit:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                       
   Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                      
   Ign:4 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/81 buster InRelease
   Hit:5 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/81 buster Release
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   All packages are up to date.
   ```

It is quite frustrating not have been able to install PHP.

Comment: The likely issue is the version of Debian that Chrome/Crouton installs doesn't (yet) include the specific versions of packages that you are after. What version of Debian are you provided with? What happens on `sudo apt install -y php`?

Comment: Did you run `apt update` to load the package cache first?

Comment: My major is difficulty is to figure out what is the version of Debian I've installed. I did run both commands and output them above

Comment: here is the problem `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.` as is described in here 
 [link]https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file[link] and for get the version from debian   
`cat /etc/debian_version` and `lsb_release -a` it must be enough to get the correct repo

Comment: You are mixing different pieces together without taking the time to understand and learn what they do. You also installed Visual Studio Code as I can see. You are going to have more problems in the future, like being unable to access your "development environment". Others have been there already with that attitude. Hint: you are using LXD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you did not successfully add the PPA (additional repository) to your container, as instructed in your first link.

The instructions on that site indicate that you need to know which version of Debian you're running.  The quickest way to do that on many Linux distributions is

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Based on your ouptut from `apt update` I suspect you are running Buster (Debian 9)

To get the additional APT repository, follow these steps

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y curl wget gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release apt-transport-https
wget https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo apt-key add apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list
sudo apt update
```

You will then be able to install the version of PHP you want

```
sudo apt -y install php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-common
php -v
PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:03:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: for me `lsb_release -sc` outputs `stable` so I manually changed to `stretch` ---> `echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list`